# Algebraic Manipulation of Summation

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to use algebraic manipulation to rewrite the sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt {(k^3-x)}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {(k^3+x)}}$$

I think I'm supposed to write it using matrices $Ax = b$ for linear algebra but I'm not sure I'm on the right path. Is that the right path? How do I write $\frac{1}{\sqrt {(k^3-x)}}$ as a matrix?

Comment: Why in the world do you think this has anything to do with linear algebra?

Comment: @TedShifrin Because the manipulation is algebraic and there are lines between numerator and denominator. ;-)

Comment: What @PrzemysławScherwentke said is my reasoning

Comment: This question is in sore need of some context in terms of what course this is from, what topic (e.g., the chapter title) the OP is studying, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this exercise, as we can guess, there are expected algebraic manipulations to obtain a form more convenient for computations. For example:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt {(k^3-x)}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {(k^3+x)}}
=\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{\sqrt {(k^3-x)}+\sqrt {(k^3+x)}}{\sqrt{k^6-x^2}}.
$$
But all depends on a goal of such algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Thank you, that helps.